# No funciona el botón de editar en proyecto en Next de la página https://nextjs.org/learn

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

Antes que nada quiero aclarar que recién estoy aprendiendo Next y typescript, este es mi primer proyecto/tutorial que sigo en Next.-

Estoy siguiendo paso a paso el tutorial del proyecto en Next con typscript.

https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app

El botón de editar no quiere funcionar, en el paso 12 en la etiqueda de **Updating an Invoice**

https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data#updating-an-invoice

Aqui el codigo app/dashboard/invoices/[id]/edit/page.tsx:

```
import Form from '@/app/ui/invoices/edit-form';
import Breadcrumbs from '@/app/ui/invoices/breadcrumbs';
import { fetchInvoiceById, fetchCustomers } from '@/app/lib/data';

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const id = params.id;
  const [invoice, customers] = await Promise.all([
    fetchInvoiceById(id),
    fetchCustomers(),
  ]);
  
  return (
    <main>
      <Breadcrumbs
        breadcrumbs={[
          { label: 'Invoices', href: '/dashboard/invoices' },
          {
            label: 'Edit Invoice',
            href: `/dashboard/invoices/${id}/edit`,
            active: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
      <Form invoice={invoice} customers={customers} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Falla en la linea que tiene el código: `<Form invoice={invoice} customers={customers} />`

Este es el error que arroja

```
Type '{ amount: number; id: string; customer_id: string; status: "pending" | "paid"; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'InvoiceForm'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'InvoiceForm'.ts(2322)
edit-form.tsx(18, 3): The expected type comes from property 'invoice' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { invoice: InvoiceForm; customers: CustomerField[]; }'
```

Este es el fetchInvoiceById

```
export async function fetchInvoiceById(id: string) {
  noStore();
  try {
    const data = await sql<InvoiceForm>`
      SELECT
        invoices.id,
        invoices.customer_id,
        invoices.amount,
        invoices.status
      FROM invoices
      WHERE invoices.id = ${id};
    `;

    const invoice = data.rows.map((invoice) => ({
      ...invoice,
      // Convert amount from cents to dollars
      amount: invoice.amount / 100,
    }));

    return invoice[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database Error:', error);
  }
}
```

y este es el InvoiceForm

```
export type InvoiceForm = {
  id: string;
  customer_id: string;
  amount: number;
  status: 'pending' | 'paid';
};
```

El código que estoy desarrollando se puede ver en:

https://github.com/rrg1459/nextjs-dashboard

No quiero sonar muuy novato, en mi local funciona, en producción falla:

Al hacer clic en el botón de editar.

https://nextjs-dashboard-zeta-topaz.vercel.app/dashboard/invoices

¿Alguna idea que me pueda orientar para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Si escribes el tipo de función para "fetchInvoiceById"

```
export async function fetchInvoiceById(
  id: string
): Promise<InvoiceForm | undefined> {...
```

Puede devolver "undefined".

Pero `EditInvoiceForm` no espera un "undefined"

```
export default function EditInvoiceForm({
  invoice,
  customers,
}: {
  invoice: InvoiceForm;
```

Puedes manejar undefined

```
  const [invoice, customers] = await Promise.all([
    fetchInvoiceById(id),
    fetchCustomers(),
  ]);

  if (invoice === undefined) {
    return;
  }
```

O forzar con "invoice!"

```
   <Form invoice={invoice!} customers={customers} />
```

Pero se cambiares el catch con "throw new Error("Failed to fetch invoice.");"

```
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Database Error:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch invoice.");
  }
```

fetchInvoiceById va a ser sin "undefined" y problema resuelto

```
export async function fetchInvoiceById(id: string): Promise<InvoiceForm> {
```